# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException adding to a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When I attempt to add a picture to our database I get the error,

> "InvalidOperationException: A dependent property in a
>   ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column:
>   'JobID'."

I think it's trying to save the information in the `job` table, instead of the `jobPic` table. I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// GET: jobPics/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.JobID = new SelectList(db.jobPics, "JobID", "Description");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: jobPics/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "JobID,Before,After")] jobPic jobPics)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.jobPics.Add(jobPics);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.JobID = new SelectList(db.jobPics, "JobID", "Description", jobPics.JobID);
        return View(jobPics);
    }
```

[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydhhj.png)

Comment: It means that `JobPic.JobID` is an identity column, but it shouldn't be, because it  draws its value from the `Job` it belongs to.

Comment: So I guess my question should be, How do I add to the Before, After table? The JobID is already in the Jobs table. How can I get the JobID then add that with the information I'm trying to add to the JobPics table.